# How to link IRC and Google Talk?

Tags: xmpp, irc, google-talk

I am looking for a way to link IRC to Google Talk.

At the moment we use [Partychatapp for google talk](http://partychapp.appspot.com/) and we'd like to find a way to migrate to using IRC.

The vision is to have everyone in an IRC room and we'd be able to have a google talk bot people could use to talk to the room.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 8):

You want [bitlbee](http://www.bitlbee.org/main.php/news.r.html).  It looks like an IRC server to IRC clients and gateways to other IM protocols.

Comment: Thanks GoS!  This looks CLOSE (and I've taken a quick look at this before).  From what I understand Bitlbee is an irc server as well.  I think what I want is more of an IRC bot.  Assume there is a preexisting irc server and channel I want to integrate this with.

Comment: I don't think you'll find much in the way of bots because dealing with multiple users on either side is painful at best — and you need either one bot to rule them all, or you need some way to keep them from triggering on each other and looping.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an application that does exactly this: https://github.com/PaulFreund/I2X 
Multiple Users use it on a daily base and there are Ideas to expand it further.

At the moment it logs on to a XMPP account and to an IRC channel, and translates between the two. It works as-is without problems but could be better, if there were more users I probably had more interrest in developing it further.

Comment: Did you purge your github account? I keep getting a 404.

Comment: n/mind I see what happened. Editing your response to point to your new userid.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry about that, I also refactored the code a little bit and it's easier to install now

Answer (score 2):

I played with bitlbee a few years ago.  Unless it's changed, it's not actually an IRC server, it just pretends to be one.  It provides an irc-flavored proxy to the jabber server, so you can use your favorite IRC client to connect to a jabber server via bitlbee.